# Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError: Calling "setOption" method on RC4

Tags: 8, theming

I'm porting [light_skeleton](https://www.drupal.org/project/light_skeleton) to Drupal 8, and it was working fine on RC2 but I ran into this issue after updating to Drupal 8 RC4.

```
Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError: Calling "setOption" method on a "Drupal\Core\Url" object is not allowed in "themes/light_skeleton/template/html.html.twig" at line 55. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigSandboxPolicy->checkMethodAllowed() (line 101 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigSandboxPolicy.php).
```

After debugging I find out that it was due to this line:

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url.setOptions({'set_active_class' : TRUE, 'attributes' : {'class' : 'navbar-link'}})) }}
```

Which I stole from - [Custom classes for menu links](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/141378/drupal-8-custom-classes-for-menu-links)  and it was working until RC4.

My question is what I'm doing wrong in here ? All I'm doing in there is setting up a variable into the links and in addition setting up the links if the link is active.

There seem to be a similar issue with the bear skin theme. You can look at this issue [Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError](https://www.drupal.org/node/2615480)

**Update**

Here is the results after debuggin on item.url `{{ kint(item.url) }}`
RC4 (this is the one that does not work)
[image: RC4 kint(item.url)]

RC2 - this how it use to be and it was working.

[image: RC2 kint(item.url)]

Comment: What `item.url` is in your context? And what it is in context you stole from? Tried to `var_dump` (or whatever equivalent there is in twig) both?

Comment: @Mołot, I have attached two screenshot debugging information about `item.url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core recently added a default sandbox so that it's not possible to e.g. call the delete method on node objects.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2513266, you can bring it up there and try to allow it, try to extend it yourself or call that option in preprocess. Not sure what the best option is.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today. for me i had the same use of setOptions to add class to the menu link. I manage to solve it after reading [Functions - In Twig Templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/2486991)

So instead of using setOptions() with attributes i could just use
`{{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['nav__link']}) }}` to solve it.

Comment: But does not filter to the active element right ? The only thing that it does is adding the class.

Comment: Correct that just adds the class. Although if you only use one level on menu it ads the is-active class by itself. With that said, if you take a look at   `core/themes/classy/templates/navigation/menu.html.twig` they use menu-item--active-trail to target node/subnode and give parent indication on active trail.